# Save method in cocoatouch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

What is the save method for cocoatouch?

I need to add it where the comment is: // whatever you want to do.

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)ntype {
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"hide"]) {
        // whatever you want to do.
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as one "save method" for Cocoa Touch.  What, specifically, do you want to save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean saving settings, you would usually use the NSUserDefaults.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"ShouldDoSomething"];
```

And to get it back

```
BOOL shouldDoSomething = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ShouldDoSomething"];
```

Obviously you can set other things aside from bools, see the documention on NSUserDefaults for more.